# How to add name below to FontImage on toolbar?

Tags: codenameone

I am using fontImages in codename one to the Toolbar. So our requirement is to set name below to that Font Images.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Command cmd = toolbar.addMaterialCommandToRightSide("Name", FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO, e -> {});
Button b = toolbar.findCommandComponent(cmd);
b.setTextPosition(Component.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Commands don't support that. You can use a custom component for the title area and add a `SpanButton` there.